# Extracting data points from over the bridge span

Tags: python, database, extract, sar, datapoint

`I am doing research on Interferometric Synthetic Aperture Radar. For this purpose, I need to extract data points from over the bridge span using Python or Matlab. I have the latitude and longitude coordinates of the bridge piers named "extracted bridge.csv". I have little knowledge of primary syntax usage in Python. Any kind of suggestions is welcomed.

[Python code I have tried in this solution for this purpose] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hAv3.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.